# Is it possible to detect AutoLayout constraint issues during a test run?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xctest

I would like our continuous integration server to fail whenever there is an AutoLayout constraint issue.  Is it possible to either search the logs or detect in XCTestCase when a constraint issue happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect ambiguous layout in XCTest by using hasAmbiguousLayout view property. However note that it might not return the same errors as you might see in xcode console log. Below is an example on how to detect that on your view controller. First add those extensions to your tests:

```
extension UIView {
    func recursiveSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap({ $0.recursiveSubviews() })
    }
}

extension XCTestCase {
    func checkViewControllerViewLoading(with viewController: UIViewController) {
        let window = UIWindow()
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        XCTAssert(viewController.view != nil)
        viewController.view?.setNeedsLayout()
        viewController.view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        viewController.view?.recursiveSubviews().forEach { view in
            XCTAssert(view.hasAmbiguousLayout == false)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just create a unit test like this:

```
func testMyViewControllerViewLoading() {
    checkViewControllerViewLoading(with: MyViewController())
}
```

And if you try to run this test with a view controller below it will fail unless you uncomment the line with width constraint.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label1)
        view.addSubview(label2)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            label1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            label1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            label2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.rightAnchor),
            label2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            label2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            // uncomment this line to have a proper layout
            // label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
}
```